# Как наложить текст на фон?

Tags: html, css

Как можно сделать, чтобы текст был на фоне? Хотелось бы чтобы заголовок(и другие добавочные текста были на фоне)
Вот код html:

```
<body>
    <h1 id = "title">Путеводитель по городам</h1>
    <img class = "bg_image"
         src = "image/background-photo.jpg"
         alt = "background for site">
</body>
```

и css:

```
#title {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Playbill;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.bg_image {
    background: url("image/background-photo.jpg");
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Вот как выглядит на данный момент[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

например так можно

```css
#title {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Playbill;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 40px;
    
    background-image: url("http://tvoyposter.ru/userdata/image/thumbs/p/17/b4/17b4fa73d392b4ec697a16c8ebc39416_p.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
    
    border: 1px solid black;

    width: 500px;
    height: 75px;
    line-height: 75px;
    
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id = "title">Путеводитель по городам</div>
```

P.S.

а вы кстати зачем то еще для img продублировали изображение через задний фон

Comment: А так получается, что мое изображение разчетверилось и занимает лишь 10% экрана, можно ли как нибудь отформатировать под весь размер фотографии?

Comment: поиграйтесь с параметром `background-size:` и параметром `background-repeat:`